# Manga where the female lead is a maid/housekeeper who works in the countryside for for an old, antisocial wizard

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead leaves her former job as a maid as her former boss, a fat noble who was the reason she was fired as he lusted for her. His wife got jealous and fired her, so the female lead goes to the countryside and becomes a maid/housekeeper for this tall old man who wears mostly button up shirts and jeans. The old man is a quiet and antisocial person, who is a wizard that can control waves upon waves of animals & cats (I think he can control weather). The noble wants her back, but she says no.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I don’t remember the hair color but it was in black & white

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Re-employment Life With an Unsociable Untalkative Magician](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/wgu9yuv/einen-koyou-wa-kanou-deshou-ka)***...?

> Lucille was recently fired from her job as a maid after an adultery scandal. This is her re-employment life story with a silent unfriendly magician in a quiet town, away from the scandals.

In her old job as a maid, Lucille worked for a noble couple, during which time she was subjected to sexual harassment from the husband and harsh treatment from the jealous wife, who ultimately fired her.

> [image: "Re-employment Life With an Unsociable Untalkative Magician," chapter 1, page 5.]

Wanting a more peaceful life, Lucille takes a train out of town and goes to work for an unsociable, taciturn magician known as 'Sensei;' a tall, thin man with short grey hair, who wears dark button-up shirts and trousers.

> [image: "Re-employment Life With an Unsociable Untalkative Magician," chapter 4, page 13.]

The noble sends a butler after Lucille to persuade her to come back, and in chapter 5, he comes to do so himself, but she refuses, as the working conditions in her new job are much better than in her old one.

This angers the noble, who grabs her and looks like he's about to strike her.

Then Sensei shows up, accompanied by a wolf, tiger and bear, turns the sky stormy and threatens to sic the animals on the noble if he doesn't skedaddle, pronto.